# Any suggestion to fix oracle update statement

Tags: sql, oracle, inner-join, sql-update

I'm trying to update `table1.column_name1` with data result from a query

```
Select ID, column_name1 
from table2  
union  
Select ID, column_name2 
from table3
```

but I get this error :

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Any suggestions please, thanks :)

With the following data tables :

table1

```
ID             column_name1            
----------------------------
26                 null          
30                 null                  
34                 null
```

table2

```
ID             column_name1            
---------------------------
26                 fix          
30                 var                  
34                 fix
```

table3

```
ID             column_name2            
----------------------------
26                 fix          
30                 null                 
34                 fix
```

Desired result :

```
ID             column_name1            
-----------------------------
26                 fix
30                 var
34                 fix
```

Query:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET table1.column_name1 = (SELECT b.column_name1 
                           FROM table1 f 
                           JOIN 
                              (SELECT ID, column_name1 
                               FROM table2  
                               UNION
                               SELECT ID, column_name2 
                               FROM table3) b ON f.ID = b.ID);
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: You didn't explain exactly how the "desired" value is derived from the "inputs", but we can guess from your example. However: Is it ever possible that the value is non-`null` in **both** tables, and they are not equal? If that is never possible (although HOW WOULD YOU KNOW?) then say so. If it IS possible, then what should be the result from that? Does one of the lookup tables have priority over the other, in the case of such internal contradictions? Then, also: What if there is already a non-`null` value in your base table? Do you want to UPDATE it even in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query with `JOIN` rather than `UNION` such as in order to be able to handle null values which cause too many rows within the `UPDATE` statement in which a `WHERE` condition is also needed

```
UPDATE table1 t1
   SET t1.column_name1 = ( SELECT NVL(t3.column_name2, t2.column_name1)
                             FROM table2 t2
                             JOIN table3 t3
                               ON t3.ID = t2.ID
                            WHERE t3.ID = t1.ID )  
 WHERE EXISTS
           ( SELECT *
               FROM table2 t2
               JOIN table3 t3
                 ON t3.ID = t2.ID
              WHERE t3.ID = t1.ID )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a782a00f8d90179cdd98d0df629104c7)</kbd>

Comment: You should use t1 in exists clause.(corelated subquery)

Answer (score 1):

You are facing issue because you are trying to assign two value (same/different) to single value.

You can use `merge` as follows:

```
Merge into table1 t1
Using (SELECT coalesce(t2.column_name1, t3.column_name2) as column_name, t2.id
         FROM table2 t2
         JOIN table3 t3 ON t3.ID = t2.ID) src
ON (src.ID = t1.ID)
When matched then 
Update set t1.column_name1 = src.column_name
```